# When i rotate an image it goes off screen

Tags: image, rotation, processing

im trying to rotate an image 90 degrees but when i do it goes off screen (to the left of the window) here is my code:

here is a link to my image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uP0r.jpg

right now im just trying to get it to rotate when i press 'r' but after this i need to make it rotate when it hits the edge of the screen.

```java
PImage head;
int fizzyX = 400;
int fizzyY = 50;
int movementX=0;
int movementY=0;
float x;

void setup() {
  size(800,800);
  background(255);
  head = loadImage("Fizzy.PNG");
}

void collisionDetection() {
  if (fizzyX == (750)) {
    movementX=-1;
    key = 'a';
  }
}



void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
    movementX = -1;
    movementY = 0;
  }
  if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
    movementX = 1;
    movementY = 0;
  }
  if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
    movementX = 0;
    movementY = -1;
  }
  if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
    movementX = 0;
    movementY = 1;
  }
  if (key == 'r') {
    x = PI/2;
  }
}

void draw() {
  rotate(x);
  background(255);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(head,fizzyX,fizzyY);
  fizzyX+=movementX;
  fizzyY+=movementY;
  keyPressed();
  collisionDetection();
  translate(width/2,height/2);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rotate()` function performs rotation around the origin, which by default is at 0,0. This causes your image to rotate around the upper-left corner of the window, which causes your image to go off the screen.

If you want to rotate the image around its center, then you first have to move the origin to the center of the image. You do this using the `translate()` function, but you have to do it **before** you to the rotation.

Putting it together, it would look like this:

```java
void draw() {

  background(255);

  imageMode(CENTER);
  translate(fizzyX, fizzyY);
  rotate(x);

  image(head,0,0);

  fizzyX+=movementX;
  fizzyY+=movementY;
  collisionDetection();

}
```

Also note that you should not manually call the `keyPressed()` function. Processing will call it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that's exactly what i needed, but i don't understand why its image(head,0,0) instead of image(head,fizzyX,fizzyX) shouldn't the former put the image at the top left of the screen instead of at the values of fizzyX and Y?

Comment: @TimothyBolton Remember the coordinates are relative to the **origin**. The call to `translate()` moves the origin to `fizzyX, fizzyY`. So then if we draw something at `100,100` it will actually be at `fizzyX+100, fizzyY+100`, because everything is relative to the origin. That's why you draw something at `0,0` to put it at `fizzyX, fizzyY`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

More detailed, with my suggestions:

-Each time you press r x must increase in HALF_PI (HALF_PI is a constant defined in processing)

-Each time you do a transformation you should use pushMatrix() and popMatrix(), in order to transform only what lies between then.

-Put the origin where you want to place the figure, then rotate, and then put the figure in 0,0. This is your corrected code, and it works like a charm.

-Use PVector when possible, makes code easier to understand, less cluttered with that variableX, variableY

-X is a bad name rotationAngle would be a better one

Try it, it works and its way more legible.

```
PImage head;
PVector fizzy;
PVector movement;
float rotationAngle;

void setup(){
  size(800,800);
  fizzy=new PVector(400,50);
  movement=new PVector(0,0);
  rotationAngle=0;
  background(255);
  head = loadImage("Fizzy.png");
}

void collisionDetection() {
  if (fizzy.x == (750)) {
    movement.set(-1,0);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
    movement.set(-1,0);
  }
  if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
    movement.set (1,0);
  }
  if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
    movement.set (0,-1);
  }
  if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
    movement.set (0,1);
  }
  if (key == 'r') {  
     rotationAngle+=HALF_PI;  
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(fizzy.x,fizzy.y);
  rotate(rotationAngle);
  imageMode(CENTER);
  image(head,0,0);
  popMatrix();
  
  fizzy.add(movement);
  collisionDetection();
}
```