# Struggling to understand why my program doesnt rotate my image twice

Tags: image, rotation, processing

This program basically needs to change the direction of the image so that its facing the right way as it changes direction the following code rotates the image as it reaches the border of the window, if i change the direction immediately after it rotates, why doesn't it rotate again?

here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5XWr.jpg

```java
PImage head;
int fizzyX = 400;
int fizzyY = 50;
int movementX=0;
int movementY=0;
float x;
char direction = 'd';

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
  background(255);
  head = loadImage("Fizzy.PNG");
}

void collisionDetection() {
  if (fizzyX == (750)) {

    movementX=-1;
    key = 'a';
    x = PI/2;
  }
  if (fizzyX == (50)) {
    movementX=1;
    key = 'd';
  }
  if (fizzyY == 750) {
    movementY=-1;
    key = 'd';
  }
  if (fizzyY < 50) {
    movementY=1;
    key = 's';
  }
}



void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
    movementX = -1;
    movementY = 0;
    direction = 'l';
  }
  if (key == 'd' || key == 'D') {
    movementX = 1;
    movementY = 0;
    direction = 'r';
  }
  if (key == 'w' || key == 'W') {
    movementX = 0;
    movementY = -1;
    direction = 'u';
  }
  if (key == 's' || key == 'S') {
    movementX = 0;
    movementY = 1;
    direction = 'd';
  }
}

void rotateFizzy() {
  if (direction == 'd' && fizzyY == 750) {
    x=PI;
  }
  if (direction == 'u' && fizzyY == 50) {
    x=2*PI;
  }
}




void draw() {
  background(255);

  rotateFizzy();
  imageMode(CENTER);
  translate(fizzyX, fizzyY);
  rotate(x);

  image(head, 0, 0);


  fizzyX+=movementX;
  fizzyY+=movementY;
  collisionDetection();
}
```

sorry for the copy paste of code

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. Can you please [debug](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your program and try to narrow it down to a specific line of code that's not behaving how you expect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the other code you posted, you have to use pushMatrix() and popMatrix().
I'd posted 2 answers, the second one with many suggestions and improvements to your code

[When i rotate an image it goes off screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579415/when-i-rotate-an-image-it-goes-off-screen)